# Create a write protected USB flash drive that is completely unformattable

Tags: memorystick

I'm looking to find out how exactly I go about creating a flash drive consistent with extremely important data on it for reasons I cannot disclose, but I need to make it completely write protected in every way possible. This includes making it completely unformattable from any and all means necessary. These documents are incredibly important and there are a couple of people that don't want the person that these files are for to get hold of them and I cannot risk them reformatting them in any way to stop them.

The drive size is 512GB and is from Corsair. The files going onto this drive are big and because I cannot afford to send them on a proper external HDD as it is too big for anyone that will be storing this for the foreseeable future, so this memory stick is my only option.

Comment: You ever heard of punctuation?

Comment: how do toy intend to prevent them from substituting a blank drive, or microwaving that one?

Comment: @Jasen Microwaving? Too much troubles, just drop it in a cup of water or vinegar, isn't that much easier? :)

Comment: Take a look at these>>>https://www.amazon.com/USB-Flash-Drives-Encrypted-Data-Storage/s?rh=n%3A3151491%2Cp_n_feature_keywords_browse-bin%3A6813186011

Comment: This sounds like a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Preventing a drive from being formatted will not stop a bad actor intercepting it & just never passing it on, whether they destroy it physically or in any other way is irrelevant. Have you considered wetransfer ?

Comment: @RacilHilan that will make them wet, they will work once dried out.

Comment: Sounds like the best course of action is to use the sneaker-net.

Comment: @Jasen It was just a joke. That's why there was a smiley at the end. It's just that microwaving metal objects and electronics is inherently unsafe. There are zillions of easier and safer ways. Water may not destroy most of them (few will stop working), but a good wack of hammer definitely will. But all of that is not the point, the point is the essence of what you said, nothing can prevents them from destroying the data on a tiny USB stick.

Comment: See also this question: [Are there USB flash drives with read-only firmware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172856). There are also USB drives that without executing special commands simulates a CD-drive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the potential information blockers are not state-level actors, there is a completely different solution.

The requirements for this to work are:

- You have Internet access (It looks like you do)
- The intended reciever has Internet access (including public library or Internet-Cafe type access)
- Both parties have a computer (presummed to be true or the USB wouldn't work either)
- You and the reciever have some form of communcation where you can be sure you are talking directly to them (privacy is not required)
- You are willing to spend about half of what the flash drive would (or did) cost.

What you and the reciever need to get are:

- Some method of creating PGP keys ([GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/) is a good, OS agnostic choice)
- A file archive tool capable of dealing with large archives split into segments (WinZip and WinRAR/RAR both can handle the task and have free trial versions available and work in Window and Linux)
- Optionally, if there are serious privacy concerns, or the potential of high-level interferance, either a VPN, or TOR, or both.

In addition, you need to get:

- A domain name registration (one year and disposable is fine)
- A website hosting package which will allow enough storage for your files, and extra space for overhead, etc. (one month, six months, or more depends on how long it will take for the files to be retrieved, and what kind of package, or deal, you can find)
- Optionally, if you need annonymity to some degree, a "private" registration on the domain name.

The process, in brief, goes like this:

1. You both generate a PGP key pair, to be used only for this purpose.
2. The keys need both "signing" and "encrypting" capabilities
3. The keys are published on a public key server, pick one, any one, they are all connected anyway
4. You and the reciever exchange the "fingerprints" of your keys in some manner which assures that you are, in fact, getting the fingerprints from eachother.

   - You could send them in an email, to be sure they are not copied wrong, but the email is no guarantee that it came directly, and unaltered, from the other person.
   - A phone call, if you know their voice and their phone number is one way, in-person would be even better.
   - Google for "key signing parties" and you'll find lots of ideas about that part of it there.
5. Encrypt, and sign (not a detached signature), each of the documents you want to share (one at a time, not a single archive for all of them)
6. Using the archive tool, each, now encrypted, document is archived as a collection of archive split files
7. As a "tamper-evident" measure, each of the split files can have a detached signature created as well
8. The entire collection of split files, and detacted signatures, are uploaded to the hosted website
9. A web page is created, to be a cover page for the collection, with a link to download each split file, and the associated signature files.
10. The reciever goes to the website and downloads each split file and its signatur file.

    - And downloaded file which does not validate against the signature file is deleted and downloaded again, until verified by the signature
11. Once all the split files for one document are recieved, and verified, the original document is recreated, and verified against the embedded signature.
12. After the full file is verified, it is un-archived, and is readable by the receiver.
13. You both meet for a dinner and celebrate your success.

---

Other than the [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/) recommendation, I'll make no suggestions of where to register a website, where to host the site, which archiver to use, or any other part of the process. At each step of the way, you should be able to find many references and tutorials no how to do what's needed.

Answer (score -1):

some drives will go read-only if you write them enough, just keep adding and deleting extra files until it breaks. then it will be read-only.

this could take a long time. (perhaps months)

Comment: it's an answer, just not a particulaly useful answer

Comment: It's as valid, as an answer as the question is, as a question. Neither is practical, both are conceivable.